# How to display data in a column of a specific table on a show page in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am making a small app for artists 
each artist (user) has a gallery, and each gallery has an artist statement.

On my show page for the gallery I do this

```
<%= @gallery.artist_statement %>
```

This displays the artist statement. However when I do this in the show page for the artist (where all of that specific artist's galleries are displayed) I get an undefined method error:

```
undefined method `artist_statement' for #<Artist:0x007fc02be33828>
```

Why is this happening, and what should I be writing instead? 
in my routes galleries are nested inside of artist so I thought creating this in the artist controller would work, but it didn't :(

```
@art_statement = @artist.gallery.artist_statement
```

Comment: The clue is the in the error message. `@artist.gallery` << `gallery` here is apparently the class `Artist`. We might need to see more code, as I'm unsure how `@artist.gallery` is returning an `Artist`, yet `@gallery` is not (I'm assuming you have ~ `@gallery = artist.gallery`). More controller and view code would help for lines around this error.

Comment: Definitely post your model code so we can see if you have properly created a relationship between Artist and Gallery. (If you don't have a relationship no implicit join will occur when requesting data from the database.)

Comment: Post your show page code.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the issue was, in the view I had a `.each do |x|` loop so instead of calling `@gallery.artist_statement` i needed to be calling `x.artist_statement` instead.

Dumb mistake. Thanks everyone for your help.